# Kendo-Angular : How to create kendo grid with template on columns?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, excel-template, kendo-angular-ui

How to create kendo grid with Kendo-Angular with export:
I have kendo grid with columns.
The columns have template.
When I export grid to excel file the columns with template doesn't show

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="dataSource"
            [sortable]="true"
            [pageable]="false"
            [filterable]="false"
            [selectable]="false">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel"></button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Name">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <span></span>
     </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Category">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <span [innerHtml]="selectedProduct?.name"></span>
     </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: it should be `<span>{{selectedProduct?.name}}</span>`, that will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates are not evaluated and exported to the Excel file:

[DOCS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-known-limitations)

You can customize the exported workbook content and cell layout as demonstrated in the following example:

[EXAMPLE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-customizing-generated-workbooks)